# How can I permanently leave a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

When I join chat rooms, I usually have the tendency to leave them. But in Stack Exchange chat rooms, I cannot find a correct way of permanently leaving a chat room, I can only get offline from a chat room.

How do I leave a chat room permanently, without just going offline?

Comment: Note that even after you leave, if you ever posted in that room, you can be pinged for 7 days after leaving. If you never posted in that room and leave it, nobody can ping you. (Except mods)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a very small "leave" button below the tags and above the list of participants.

[image]

In the example image, the button is right above my profile picture.

If the "leave" button doesn't work, it's probably a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: I can't find that page, can you tell me where to find it?

Comment: @Devealte The screenshot I took is from going to the actual chat room (and looking at the top left corner).